# Liquidity Balance Sheet

Tags: calculation, financial-literacy, liquidity

Should be or should we not deduct long term debt along with current liabilities from total current assets to arrive at current asset value per share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Net Current Asset Value Per Share - NCAVPS:**

> A value created by professor Benjamin Graham in the mid-twentieth
> century to determine if a company was trading at a fair market price.
> NCAVPS is calculated by taking a company's *current assets* and
> subtracting the *total liabilities*, and then dividing the result by the
> *total number of shares outstanding.* [(Investopedia)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/ncavps.asp)

**Formula:**

(Current Assets- Total Liabilities)/Number of shares outstanding

**For example:**

XYZ company has $16 million in current assets , $6 million in current liabilities, and 2 million shares outstanding. So according to the formula we have:

NCAVPS = ($16,000,000 - $6,000,000) / 2,000,000 = $5

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to apply Benjamin Grahams definition in security analysis to some company's balance sheet report from S&P. I ran into this difficulty of finding both Current Liability and Long Term Debt. I wasn't sure if NVCAPS is less long term debt.

Comment: `- note that his (Benjamin Graham) formula for NCAVPS uses total liabilities rather than current liabilities, and typically results in a smaller number.`  **- investinganswers.com**    The reason some use it (long term debt) and some don't is LTD used properly is great for a company (leverage).  However, too much LTD can cause a company to default on the payments.  It is better to find a way to find a medium between the two equations - one that uses the upcoming debt payments - to get a good analysis.

Answer (score 1):

NCAVPS: (Current Assets- Total Liabilities) / Shares Outstanding

[Source](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/ncavps.asp)